# Google Spreadsheet Script Error: "Execution failed: You do not have permission to call prompt"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

When my Google Sheet is edited, I want a prompt to appear to the user.

This was working for me a while ago, but it is now throwing this error, and I do not *think* I changed anything.

Here is the code inside the script editor:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.prompt("this is a prompt");
}
```

The error:

> Execution failed: You do not have permission to call prompt (line 4, file "testPrompt") [0.002 seconds total runtime]

If I use an installable trigger, it works for me(sheet owner) but no one else, even if they have edit access.

Some more info; to test to see if all permission/authorization is complete for user, I did a test to see if any more auth is required, and to grab the auth url:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
ui.alert(authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus() + authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl());
```

And this is the result every time, even after I follow the URL and give auth, it continues to say that further auth is required:

```
REQUIRED
https://script.google.com/a/macros/blahblah.com/d/blahblahblah-/authorize
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask for user input in "on edit" installable trigger in Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479954/how-to-ask-for-user-input-in-on-edit-installable-trigger-in-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: @Kos, thank you. That was very helpful. Using an image did work.