# Google Sheets Installable Trigger not firing for non-owner users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am attempting to make an installable trigger fire when a spreadsheet is edited, and run a function called DutySwitch(e).

The function works fine when run from my account (owner).  But nothing happens (even in the logs or execution transcript) when another user edits the sheet.

[This is the installable trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP6dS.png).  I need the installable trigger's ability to run the authorized service of creating calendar events.

This is the beginning of the called function:

```
function DutySwitch(e) {
  Logger.log("triggered");
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10h-8rKINy56Ap5OtSum1U7jDlvrqiLaasxhYP1LkGcM");
  var dutySwitchSheet = sheets.getSheetByName('Duty Switches');
```

I have tried deleting, saving, and recreating the trigger.  I have tried revoking and returning permissions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask for user input in "on edit" installable trigger in Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479954/how-to-ask-for-user-input-in-on-edit-installable-trigger-in-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

What you need for your use case is Simple Trigger's [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) trigger.
Just make sure to share the spreadsheet to non-owners. Did this to my spreadsheet, and the onEdit() works even for non-owners.

Don't forget the '**can edit**' access type when sharing (File->Share) to non-owners.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
However, a simple trigger will not work for me because I need to create events on a single calendar that I own, and I don' t want to give others the ability to edit the Google Calendar.  Do you know of a way to make the installable trigger work?

Comment: if it works if you have 'edit' access but doesn't if you only have 'read' access, shouldn't that be telling you something already? Like how far you gonna goad the library?